# Swift PHP Post and UserDefaults

Tags: php, arrays, swift

I am working on an App which will show a form (name, last name, phone, etc.) and that information is sent to a PHP that I have on my domain. After registration, I want to show the info to the user (via UserDefauls so the info is stored).

What I don't know is how to use this property and how to change the labels on the view where I will show the information. For additional information, the information is stored in an array "str[value]"

I did something like this...

```
    let UDName = UserDefaults()
    var dataName: String?


    @IBAction func sendInfo(_ sender: Any) {
    //PHP Post process 
    //This is the String
         self.dataName = str3[0]
    //The UserDefaults... value?
         self.UDName.set(self.dataName, forKey: "name")
     }
```

Now, the Button that retrieves/shows the information:

```
    @IBAction func showInfo(_ sender: Any) {

           if let name = UDName.string(forKey: "name") {

           //This is the label from the form in the view
           labelNombre.text = name
         }    
     }
```

When I run the project, fill the textfields and save, everything is ok (prints the array with the info) but when I click the showInfo button, I get a Nil error in the code:

```
labelName.text = name
```

I appreciate your help :D

Comment: labelNombre is the same as labelName, I forgot to translate it. my bad

Comment: Do you use storyboard? Sounds like not connected outlet

Comment: yes, all labels/buttons are connected. I think it might be an Array problem when storing values in the UserDefault obj.

Comment: But you have said your error is in this line `labelName.text = name`. If it is true try to set labelName.text somewhere else with some value. If it crashes try to remove connections and add them again.

Comment: I set the label text like "labelName.text = "test" and the problem is still there. I'll do the connections again.

Comment: it Says Expected Declaration.... labelName.text ="something"

Comment: Fixed! What I did was setting the label in a different class and from there, I used the information from the UserDefaults to change the labels. So far no problems appeared. I thank you for your help cause I wouldn't even imagined the label could make this kind of problems hahaha :)

Comment: Yeah good to hear that, I ran into this couple of times, myself. Nice job